# What is latest stable SharePoint 2013 CU?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, cumulative-update, patching

What is the latest stable SharePoint 2013 Cumulative update?

CU`s from Nov - Feb, has these workflows [issues](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=784), I am not sure if these are fixed as part of any latest CU.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to always be on the CU which is 1 month prior to the current month.

That way you are on the most stable CU and aware of any issues or exceptions occurring due to the current month CU .

I have recently patched my SharePoint 2013 environment with the April 2019 patch and it looks the most stable patch right now .

Following is the information for this patch :-

**Build no** - 15.0.5127.1001

**Build name** - April 2019

**Component** - SharePoint server 2013

**KB** - KB4464514

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Updates are displayed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates

The currently latest CU is [KB 4464514 - April 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464514/april-9-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013-k)

The problem you mentioned was **not** due to a SharePoint update but rather [.net-Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4457916/security-only-updates-for-net-framework-3-5-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-4-6-2-4-7).